# Guardar ID con System.Web.HttpContext.Current

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Mi problema es que quiero guardar un ID con:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ContratacionMI"] = moldesInteligentes.Contratacion_ID.ToString();
```

y lo declaro en el controlador, así como se muestra en el código

```
public ActionResult CreateMI()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.MoldesInteligentes.Add(moldesInteligentes);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("CreateSecuencialOperaciones", new { id = moldesInteligentes.MInteligenteID});
        }
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ContratacionMI"] = moldesInteligentes.Contratacion_ID.ToString();

        return View(moldesInteligentes);
    }
```

Y cuando quiero volver a utilizar el ID guardado lo hago de esta forma:

```
TempData["contID"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ContratacionMI"] as string;
```

y lo declaro en el controlador así como se muestra en el código

```
 public ActionResult CreateOperacionesMI(int id)
    {
        TempData["contID"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ContratacionMI"] as string;

        return View();
    }


[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateOperacionesMI(Operaciones operaciones)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Operaciones.Add(operaciones);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        TempData["contID"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ContratacionMI"] as string;

        return View(operaciones);
    }
```

Todo va bien cuando llega al GET del CreateOperaciones porque ahí el TempData sí contiene el ID que guardo, pero al momento de pasar al POST del CreateOperaciones el TempData llega null.

Como se muestra en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que me pueda decir en que estoy mal por favor

Comment: Tengo una pregunta. En el método `CreateMI()` la variable de sesión se llama ContratacionMI, pero en `CreateOperacionesMI()` se llama ContratacionID. Es esto un error?

Comment: Si perdon, es que intentado de varias formas y no me fije que asi lo deje, pero de cualquier manera regresa null

Answer (score 0):

Como su propio nombre indica `TempData[]` es un sistema de almacenamiento, que te permite intercambiar datos entre diferentes Controladores, pero de **forma temporal**. El problema está en que solo es válido para una sola interacción con una Acción.

Si quieres mantener un valor constante para para toda la sesión de un usuario determinado, como por ejemplo '`contID`' o '`Session["ContratacionMI"]`', te aconsejo utilices **Cookies** y a ser posible **encriptadas** para mayor seguridad.

Como veo que utilizas ASP.NET MVC te aconsejo leas este artículo [Encriptar y desencriptar cookies en una aplicación ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/9/19/encriptar-y-desencriptar-cookies-en-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-aspnet-mvc) .